# Setting PostgreSQL options in YugabyteDB YSQL as g-flag

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I’m trying to set `enable_nestloop` permanently as a g-flag. How can I set these PostgreSQL config options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL parameters can be set with the `[--ysql_pg_conf][1]` flag as comma separated like `ysql_pg_conf=enable_nestloop=false`